# Pivoting data.table where order matters for some functions and not for some functions?

Tags: r, data.table, pivot-table, lapply, subtotal

I am practising in pivoting `data.table`, example below with `lapply` to get substructure features and their corresponding columns where ordering matters for the key column, this could be seen as pivoting in spreadsheet tools. This is similar to pivot-table and perhaps R tool called cube, other subtotal tools may be easier to use than `lapply`. I am open to comparisons to more convenient tools, `lapply` seems to become quite terse when you need more functions and particularly with different orders.

**Demo**

I form new subcategories with `paste0` in `data.table` over which I want to calculate features, such as mean and sum. Small example is below with input and intended output.

*Input*

```
> data.table(cn=c('a','a','b','b','c'),test=c(1,2,3,4,0),cat=c(1,1,1,2,2))
   cn test cat
1:  a    1   1
2:  a    2   1
3:  b    3   1
4:  b    4   2
5:  c    0   2
> myData <- data.table(cn=c('a','a','b','b','c'),test=c(1,2,3,4,0),cat=c(1,1,1,2,2))
> myData[order(test), lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse = '>'), by = c('cat')]  
   cat    cn  test
1:   2   c>b   0>4
2:   1 a>a>b 1>2>3  

#How can I add here new functions to get new columns for the segments such as a>a>b
```

*Output*

```
   cat    cn  test  test_sum test_avg
1:   1 a>a>b 1>2>3  6        2
2:   2   c>b   0>4  4        2
```

Put more simply, how can we get the output with the input? Is `lapply` the correct choice here? Notice that ordering matters for some functions and not for some functions.

### **How to pivot data.table properly where some functions needs order and some not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
#set keys for ordering
setkey(DT, cat, test )
#
DT[, .(cn       = paste0( cn, collapse = ">"),
       test     = paste0( test, collapse = ">" ),
       test_sum = sum( test ),
       test_avg = mean( test ) ), 
   by = cat ]

#    cat    cn  test test_sum test_avg
# 1:   1 a>a>b 1>2>3        6        2
# 2:   2   c>b   0>4        4        2
```

But, you can also sort inside the codeline, using `sort()`
Below, I sorted `text` in decreasing order (just to show it can be done).

```
DT[, .(cn       = paste0( cn, collapse = ">"),
       test     = paste0( sort( test, decreasing = TRUE ), collapse = ">" ),
       test_sum = sum( test ),
       test_avg = mean( test ) ), 
   by = cat ]

#    cat    cn  test test_sum test_avg
# 1:   1 a>a>b 3>2>1        6        2
# 2:   2   c>b   4>0        4        2
```

Comment: I like the simplicity, clarity here +1. Does the second case scale to any ordering? I am currently calculating things separately and then using merge (left join) to combine the results but the second case may be close if understood how to work it out with any ordering (for functions where order matter, you want to make sure they do not mix together).

Comment: If you want to sort a column before using it in a function, use something like this: `sort( data, decreasing = TRUE /FALSE)`, as seen in the second line of the second codeblock.